# Are settlement supply lines networked?

Tags: fallout-4

If I connect settlement A to settlement B, and B to C, are the items in A available to C?

Comment: *sigh* For all my searching, someone immediately found the duplicate / answer. Well I can't complain. I do think my question was more concise though. :)

Comment: Future readers: yes, they are